# user location is not visible in the map

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [[self mapView] setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    [[self locationManager] setDelegate:self];


    if ([[self locationManager] respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [[self locationManager] requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

    [[self locationManager] setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

user location is not visible in the map
iOS 9.1 
Xcode 7.1.1

Comment: simulator or device ? did u add required keys in plist ?

Comment: yes i add this key in plist NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription testing in simulator

Comment: in simulator u cant get the user location, you can only simulate a location!!!

Comment: from the simulator's menu choose Debug > Location > Custom Location....

Comment: Thanks ! It Worked In Device